# InnoSetup takes wrong files

Tags: inno-setup

Today i encountered an odd problem. 
In the Files Section i have two different .exe files, which are copied into the temp folder to do some stuff, and then disappear at installation time. All worked fine until the compiler took a version of my .exe and decided, that it won't take any other version of it. I recompiled it several times, deleted all Temp folder entries belonging to InnoSetup, restartet the PC, placed the new version of my .exe in another path and added it to the Setup, i even deleted all Versions of this .exe and built a new one, but nothing helped. InnoSetup refuses to take another Version of this .exe whatever i do.

Well then, here some Code:

```
[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "german"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"

[Components]
Name: "Client"; Description: "Client"; Types: Client Full;
Name: "Database"; Description: "Database preparation"; Types: Full;

[Types]
Name: "Full"; Description: "Full Installtion (Client and Database)"
Name: "Client"; Description: "Client Only (Database needed)";

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked;

[Files]
Source: "C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\Client\Client.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\Client\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\MySqlDbCreation.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\ClientCopyData-20140722-1208.sql"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "C:\Users\d.volz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XMLAndIniReplacer\XMLAndIniReplacer\bin\Release\XMLAndIniReplacer.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[Code]
var
  DBPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  Database: bool;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  DBPage := CreateInputQueryPage(7, ExpandConstant('{cm:DBPageHeader}'), ExpandConstant('{cm:DBPageSubHead}'), ExpandConstant('{cm:DBPageDescription}'));
  DBPage.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:DBPageServ}'), False);
  DBPage.Add('Port:', False);
  DBPage.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:DBPageUserName}'), False);
  DBPage.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:DBPagePass}'), True);

  DBPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData(ExpandConstant('{cm:DBPageServ}'), '');
  DBPage.Values[1] := GetPreviousData('Port:', '');
  DBPage.Values[2] := GetPreviousData(ExpandConstant('{cm:DBPageUserName}'), '');
  DBPage.Values[3] := GetPreviousData(ExpandConstant('{cm:DBPagePass}'), '');

  ExtractTemporaryFile('MySqlDbCreation.exe');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('ClientCopyData-20140722-1208.sql');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('XMLAndIniReplacer.exe');
end;


procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
ResultCode : Integer;
begin
    if CurStep=ssPostInstall then begin
        Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\XMLAndIniReplacer.exe',ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\Client.exe.config'+ ' ' +DBPage.Values[0] + ' ' + DBPage.Values[1] + ' ' + ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\Client.ini' + ' ' + ExpandConstant('{language}'),'', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) 
    end;       
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then begin
  end;
end;


function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
  var
    ResultCode: Integer;
  begin
    Result := True;
    if CurPageID = DBPage.ID then begin
      if DBPage.Values[0] = '' then begin
        MsgBox('You must enter the server name or address.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end else if DBPage.Values[1] = '' then begin
        MsgBox('You must enter a port, even the default one.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end else if DBPage.Values[2] = '' then begin
        MsgBox('You must enter the user name.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end else if DBPage.Values[3] = '' then begin
        MsgBox('You must enter the user password.',mbError,MB_OK);
        Result := False; 
      end else if Database then begin
        if MsgBox('Database will now be prepared for Client. Continue?',mbConfirmation,MB_OKCANCEL) = IDOK then begin
          if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\MySqlDbCreation.exe', DBPage.Values[0] + ' ' + DBPage.Values[1] + ' ' + DBPage.Values[2] + ' ' + DBPage.Values[3] + ' ' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\ClientCopyData-20140722-1208.sql', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then begin
            if ResultCode = 0 then begin
              MsgBox('Database was created successfully. Clientcan now be installed',mbInformation,MB_OK);
              Result := True;
            end else if ResultCode = 1 then begin
              if MsgBox('Could not create database for Client. Do you wish to proceed the setup anyway? Client can not be used without a database.',mbError,MB_YESNO) = IDYES then begin
                Result := true;
              end else begin
                Result := false;
              end;
            end else if ResultCode = 2 then begin
              if MsgBox('Could not connect to the Database. Do you wish to proceed the setup anyway? Client can not be used without a database.',mbError,MB_YESNO) = IDYES then begin
              Result := True;
              end else begin 
              Result := false;
              end;
            end else begin
              MsgBox('Invalid number of Arguments',mbError,MB_OK);
              Result := false;
            end;
          end;
        end else begin
          if MsgBox('Client can not be used without a prepared database. Do you wish to continue the setup anyway? ',mbError,MB_YESNO) = IDYES then begin;
          Result := true;
          end else begin
          Result := false;
          end;
        end; 
      end; 
    end;
  end;
```

MySqlDbCreation and XmlAndIniReplacer are two little C# Consoles.

Whatever i do, InnoSetup takes a version of XmlAndIniReplacer which i don't even have anymore instead of the one specified in the Files Section. Also it won't recognize the Flag dontcopy, which means, i can find the Console in the Application Folder. Whats wrong here?

Compiler:

```
*** Starting compile.  [16:46:00]

[ISPP] Preprocessing.
[ISPP] Preprocessed.

Parsing [Setup] section, line 14
Parsing [Setup] section, line 15
Parsing [Setup] section, line 16
Parsing [Setup] section, line 18
Parsing [Setup] section, line 19
Parsing [Setup] section, line 20
Parsing [Setup] section, line 21
Parsing [Setup] section, line 22
Parsing [Setup] section, line 23
Parsing [Setup] section, line 24
Parsing [Setup] section, line 25
Parsing [Setup] section, line 26
Parsing [Setup] section, line 27
Parsing [Setup] section, line 28
Reading file (WizardImageFile)
   File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\WIZMODERNIMAGE.BMP
Reading file (WizardSmallImageFile)
   File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\WIZMODERNSMALLIMAGE.BMP
Preparing Setup program executable
Reading default messages from Default.isl
Parsing [Languages] section, line 31
   File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Default.isl
Parsing [Languages] section, line 32
   File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Languages\German.isl
Parsing [LangOptions], [Messages], and [CustomMessages] sections
   Messages in script file
Reading [Code] section
Parsing [Types] section, line 39
Parsing [Types] section, line 40
Parsing [Components] section, line 35
Parsing [Components] section, line 36
Parsing [Tasks] section, line 43
Parsing [Tasks] section, line 44
Parsing [Icons] section, line 53
Parsing [Icons] section, line 54
Parsing [Icons] section, line 55
Parsing [Icons] section, line 56
Parsing [Run] section, line 59
Parsing [Files] section, line 47
Parsing [Files] section, line 48
   Reading version info: C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\MySqlDbCreation.exe
Parsing [Files] section, line 49
   Reading version info: C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\ClientCopyData-20140722-1208.sql
Parsing [Files] section, line 50
   Reading version info: C:\Users\d.volz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XMLAndIniReplacer\XMLAndIniReplacer\bin\Release\XMLAndIniReplacer.exe
Compiling [Code] section
Deleting ClientSetup.exe from output directory
Creating setup files

   Compressing: Intensifies...

   Compressing: C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\MySqlDbCreation.exe   (1.0.0.0)
   Compressing: C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\ClientCopyData-20140722-1208.sql
   Compressing: C:\Users\d.volz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XMLAndIniReplacer\XMLAndIniReplacer\bin\Release\XMLAndIniReplacer.exe   (1.0.0.0)
   Compressing Setup program executable
   Updating version info

*** Finished.  [16:46:22, 00:21,809 elapsed]
```

Comment: Updated it. Hope its more understandable now.

Comment: Much better. Thanks. :-) What is this line in `[Files]` supposed to do? `Source: "C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\Client\*";` You've already included `Client.exe` from that folder. It's also a little unclear still what problem you're having. You mention the two .exe files that go into temp and are deleted after, but then go on to talk about "my .exe" and "the .exe", and I don't know if it's one of the two that go into temp or if it's one of the others.

Comment: Yeah, but there is a whole bunch of .dlls and other things that have to be delivered too.

Comment: Then list them. I don't think `*` works like you think it does there, and if it did you could then remove the separate line for Client.exe.

Comment: both go into the temp folder as you can see, but the problem is, that the Replacer InnoSetup uses is not the one i specified in the Files Section. The wizard asked for the main executeable, and for other files. Thought i could trust it ;)

Comment: What does the compiler output window show you is happening? (View->Compiler Output) Look for `Parsing [Files] section, line xx` and `Creating setup files` followed by `Compressing: filename`.

Comment: `Parsing [Files] section, line 47
Parsing [Files] section, line 48
   Reading version info: C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\MySqlDbCreation.exe
Parsing [Files] section, line 49
   Reading version info: C:\MM-DISTRIBUTION\ClientCopyData-20140722-1208.sql
Parsing [Files] section, line 50
   Reading version info: C:\Users\d.volz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XMLAndIniReplacer\XMLAndIniReplacer\bin\Release\XMLAndIniReplacer.exe
Compiling [Code] section
Deleting ClientSetup.exe from output directory
Creating setup files`

And then it is compressing many files.

Comment: So use that compiler output. Rename the XMLAndIniReplacer.exe to XMLAndIniReplacerNew.exe in both the script and the folder, and then build again and check the compiler output. Is it now using the renamed file? (And I meant for you to check those "many files" being compressed to see if the problem file is one of them, or if it was using a file from a cached copy somewhere.)

Comment: Well it works... but why now?

Comment: Because it isn't seeing a change in the version, and so it was using a previous cached copy you missed somewhere. Renaming meant it had to use a different file. If you change the names back, it should pick up the new version now. You know both how to fix it, and how to troubleshoot future problems. :-)

Comment: *Head hits table* I thought of the cache, but not of that. So close *sigh*. Thanks for that :D

Comment: I've done a quick writeup of the solution, in case it's of benefit to someone having the same problem in the future.

Comment: @Ken, I don't think there's some intermediate disk cache for `[Files]`. But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @TLama: No, but for *compressed files* there may be. If the version number between the source file and the *compressed* version of that file are the same between builds, there's no reason to compress it again. (There would have to be an intermediate cache; some builds get very large, and I don't think everything could fit in memory at once.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears InnoSetup is finding information in a cache somewhere, noticing that the version hasn't changed, and is using that cached copy instead because it's already compressed and can save time.

Here's a way to fix it:

Build your setup. Use the Compiler Output window (*View->Compiler Output*) to see exactly what files are being included. You should check both the *Parsing [Files]* and *Compressing:* sections of that output. Note the exact path and filename it's using for the file(s) that are the issue.

Rename the problem file, both in the folder it's in and in the *[Files]* section in your installer script. Build the installation again, and check the compiler output to make sure it picked up the renamed file when it was parsing.

Change the script and file back to their original names. It should now start using the new version of the file as you originally wanted.